# What is define function?

Tags: php

What is define function?
And how require once function works with define function ?

example :

```
define('ABSPATH',dirname(__FILE__).'/');
require_once(ABSPATH.'homepage.php');
```

help me guys.

Comment: RTFM : `Defines a named constant at runtime. ` http://php.net/define

Comment: You need to [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `define()` function defines a constant. Constants are automatically global and can be used across the entire script.

In your example `define('ABSPATH',dirname(FILE).'/');` ,defines a constant named ABSPATH, whose value is the result of `dirname(FILE).'/'` ie, parent directory's path with a trailing slash

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'homepage.php'); includes the file
```

[See](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Comment: thnks for ur answers and my another question is how the define('abs',nav');require_once(abs.nav.'/index.php') works..